"no such user" - LDAP authentication with sssd
I am struggling with making sssd use LDAP users to login on my Linux-Server (Oracle Linux 8.9, basically identical to RHEL, but free).
Goal
Using the users (e.g. "John") existing on the LDAP-Server (Microsoft AD DC) to log in on my Linux-Server
Current Errors
Whenever I enter the command "id John" or "su - John" I receive the error "no such user".
Strangely, all my sssd logs are not showing anything. The logs itself are working, because I had other issues before (e.g. "Port working, but In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection"), but I managed to solve all this problems using the logs.
But currently, nothing new gets printed to the logs, no matter if I use "id" or "su"
What is working
"ldapsearch" is working perfectly fine and prints out my LDAP-Tree - including "John"
ldapsearch -D "CN=mybind,OU=myunit,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com" -W

Right now I really do not have any idea anymore why it is not working. I double and triple checked all IPs etc.
In my opinion it should work, or at least give me usable logs. Any help is appreciated.
/etc/openldap/ldap.conf
# See ldap.conf(5) for details
# This file should be world readable but not world writable.

BASE    DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
URI     ldaps://dc.my.domain.com:636
TLS_CACERT      /etc/openldap/cacerts/ca.cert.pem
TLS_CACERTDIR /etc/openldap/cacerts

#SIZELIMIT      12
#TIMELIMIT      15
#DEREF          never

# When no CA certificates are specified the Shared System Certificates
# are in use. In order to have these available along with the ones specified
# by TLS_CACERTDIR one has to include them explicitly:
#TLS_CACERT     /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem

# System-wide Crypto Policies provide up to date cipher suite which should
# be used unless one needs a finer grinded selection of ciphers. Hence, the
# PROFILE=SYSTEM value represents the default behavior which is in place
# when no explicit setting is used. (see openssl-ciphers(1) for more info)
#TLS_CIPHER_SUITE PROFILE=SYSTEM

# Turning this off breaks GSSAPI used with krb5 when rdns = false
#SASL_NOCANON   on

/etc/sssd/sssd.conf
    [sssd]
    config_file_version = 2
    services = nss, pam, autofs
    domains = default
    
    [nss]
    
    homedir_substring = /export/home
    
    [pam]
    
    [domain/default]
    id_provider = ldap
    autofs_provider = ldap
    auth_provider = ldap
    chpass_provider = ldap
    ldap_schema = AD
    ldap_uri = ldaps://dc.my.domain.com:636
    ldap_chpass_uri = ldaps://dc.my.domain.com:636
    ldap_search_base = DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
    ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
    ldap_tls_cacertdir = /etc/openldap/cacerts
    ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
    cache_credentials = False
    entry_cache_timeout = 600
    ldap_network_timeout = 3
    ldap_connection_expire_timeout = 60
    ldap_default_bind_dn = CN=mybind,OU=myunit,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com
    ldap_default_authtok = mypassword

/etc/nsswitch.conf
# Generated by authselect on Tue May  7 10:30:31 2024
# Do not modify this file manually.

# If you want to make changes to nsswitch.conf please modify
# /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf and run 'authselect apply-changes'.
#
# Note that your changes may not be applied as they may be
# overwritten by selected profile. Maps set in the authselect
# profile takes always precedence and overwrites the same maps
# set in the user file. Only maps that are not set by the profile
# are applied from the user file.
#
# For example, if the profile sets:
#     passwd: sss files
# and /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf contains:
#     passwd: files
#     hosts: files dns
# the resulting generated nsswitch.conf will be:
#     passwd: sss files # from profile
#     hosts: files dns  # from user file

passwd:     files sss systemd
group:      files sss systemd
netgroup:   sss files
automount:  sss files
services:   sss files

# Included from /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf

#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# Valid databases are: aliases, ethers, group, gshadow, hosts,
# initgroups, netgroup, networks, passwd, protocols, publickey,
# rpc, services, and shadow.
#
# Valid service provider entries include (in alphabetical order):
#
#       compat                  Use /etc files plus *_compat pseudo-db
#       db                      Use the pre-processed /var/db files
#       dns                     Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#       files                   Use the local files in /etc
#       hesiod                  Use Hesiod (DNS) for user lookups
#       nis                     Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#       nisplus                 Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#
# See `info libc 'NSS Basics'` for more information.
#
# Commonly used alternative service providers (may need installation):
#
#       ldap                    Use LDAP directory server
#       myhostname              Use systemd host names
#       mymachines              Use systemd machine names
#       mdns*, mdns*_minimal    Use Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD
#       resolve                 Use systemd resolved resolver
#       sss                     Use System Security Services Daemon (sssd)
#       systemd                 Use systemd for dynamic user option
#       winbind                 Use Samba winbind support
#       wins                    Use Samba wins support
#       wrapper                 Use wrapper module for testing
#
# Notes:
#
#
# WARNING: Running nscd with a secondary caching service like sssd may
#          lead to unexpected behaviour, especially with how long
#          entries are cached.
#
# Installation instructions:
#
# To use 'db', install the appropriate package(s) (provide 'makedb' and
# libnss_db.so.*), and place the 'db' in front of 'files' for entries
# you want to be looked up first in the databases, like this:
#
# passwd:    db files
# shadow:    db files
# group:     db files

# In order of likelihood of use to accelerate lookup.
shadow:     files sss
hosts:      files dns myhostname

aliases:    files
ethers:     files
gshadow:    files
# Allow initgroups to default to the setting for group.
# initgroups: files
networks:   files dns
protocols:  files
publickey:  files
rpc:        files

Update
ssd_default.log with debug_level 6
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_get_account_info_send] (0x0200): Got request for [0x1][BE_REQ_USER][name=John@default]
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#6] DP Request [Account #6]: REQ_TRACE: New request. [sssd.nss CID #2] Flags [0x0001].
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#6] Number of active DP request: 1
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sdap_search_user_next_base] (0x0400): [RID#6] Searching for users with base [dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com]
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0400): [RID#6] calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(sAMAccountName=John)(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(&(uidNumber=*)(!(uidNumber=0))))][dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com].
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sdap_get_generic_op_finished] (0x0400): [RID#6] Search result: Success(0), no errmsg set
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sdap_search_user_process] (0x0400): [RID#6] Search for users, returned 0 results.
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sysdb_search_by_name] (0x0400): [RID#6] No such entry
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sysdb_delete_user] (0x0400): [RID#6] Error: 2 (No such file or directory)
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_req_done] (0x0400): [RID#6] DP Request [Account #6]: Request handler finished [0]: Success
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [_dp_req_recv] (0x0400): [RID#6] DP Request [Account #6]: Receiving request data.
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): [RID#6] DP Request [Account #6]: Request removed.
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): [RID#6] Number of active DP request: 0
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): sssd.dataprovider.getAccountInfo: Success
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_get_account_info_send] (0x0200): Got request for [0x1][BE_REQ_USER][idnumber=John]
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#7] DP Request [Account #7]: REQ_TRACE: New request. [sssd.nss CID #2] Flags [0x0001].
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): [RID#7] Number of active DP request: 1
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sdap_search_user_next_base] (0x0400): [RID#7] Searching for users with base [dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com]
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0400): [RID#7] calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(uidNumber=John)(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(&(uidNumber=*)(!(uidNumber=0))))][dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com].
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sdap_get_generic_op_finished] (0x0400): [RID#7] Search result: Success(0), no errmsg set
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sdap_search_user_process] (0x0400): [RID#7] Search for users, returned 0 results.
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sysdb_search_user_by_uid] (0x0400): [RID#7] No such entry
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sysdb_delete_user] (0x0400): [RID#7] Error: 2 (No such file or directory)
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_req_done] (0x0400): [RID#7] DP Request [Account #7]: Request handler finished [0]: Success
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [_dp_req_recv] (0x0400): [RID#7] DP Request [Account #7]: Receiving request data.
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): [RID#7] DP Request [Account #7]: Request removed.
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): [RID#7] Number of active DP request: 0
(2024-05-08  7:59:45): [be[default]] [sbus_issue_request_done] (0x0400): sssd.dataprovider.getAccountInfo: Success


If your authentication service is AD why are you using the LDAP connector rather than the AD one?

Because that would require an AD-join with realmd, no? And our windows administrators do not want to have linux servers appearing in the domain tree (don't ask me why, it was a discussion I could not win).
But using ldap should work, since I have a running instance of netbox on the given server, which is using ldap to authenticate the web application users. Using the same parameters for netbox as I did for sssd is working perfectly, but I don't get why it isn't working for sssd

Thanks. Really helpful to understand why you weren't taking the "obvious" route

Looking at the log files with debug_level = 6 enabled, it's evident that the LDAP query is being performed but no results are returned:

[RID#6] Searching for users with base [dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com]
[RID#6] calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(sAMAccountName=John)(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=*)(&(uidNumber=*)(!(uidNumber=0))))][dc=my,dc=domain,dc=com].
[RID#6] Search result: Success(0), no errmsg set
[RID#6] Search for users, returned 0 results.


The issue here turns out to be that the uidNumber value is not populated in the Active Directory (AD/LDAP) source. The correct solution here is to ensure that the UID and GID are derived from the AD SID value:
ldap_id_mapping = true

